# Using coordinating conjunction with conjunctival adverbs

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions, punctuation

Why do we omit the comma that comes after a conjunctival adverbs when the adverb is preceded by a coordinating conjunction?

> - My dog had got provoked./; Therefore, he bit my friend.
> - My dog had got provoked, and therefore he bit my friend.

Comment: Because we get along fine without them. You don't need one after **provoked** either.

Comment: It all depends on how much you like commas.  It's fine to write *"... provoked, and, therefore, he bit my friend"*.  Commas for everyone!

Comment: You mean we could write it this way: “My dog had got provoked and therefore bit my friend”? @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: Yes, you could write it that way.